# Proving a metric induces the product topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-verification

> Let $(M,d)$ and $(N,d')$ be metric spaces. Prove that the product topology is induced by the metric $d_1((x,y),(x',y')=d(x,x')+d(y,y')$ and $d_2((x,y),(x',y'))=\operatorname{max}\{d(x,y),d'(x',y')\}$.

I have to say, that I truly have no idea how to prove that a metric induces a certain topology, my guess here is to just  consider the topology induced by the metric as well as the product topology and show that they are included in each other.

I don't have a complete proof, but I wrote  a couple of things following that idea:

$(1)$ Let $T$ be the product topology and $T_i$ be the topology induced by the metric $d_i$.

A basis for the product topology of $M\times N$ contains sets of the form $U\times V$ where $U$ is open in $M$ and $V$ is open in $N$; and a basis for the topology induced by $T_1$ would be the sets of open balls according to the metric $d_1$, this is, the set of all open balls where each ball si given by $$B_{1}((x,y),r) = \{(x',y')\in M\times N:d_1((x,y),(x',y'))<r\}$$ In terms of the metric $d,d'$ the balls could be expressed as $$B_{1}((x,y),r) = \{(x',y')\in M\times N:d(x,y)+d'(x',y')<r\}$$

Which means I need to show that for $(x,y)\in U\times V$ open in $M\times N$ there is a ball such that $$(x,y)\in B_1((x,y),r)\subset U\times V$$

Now, what are exactly those open sets $U$ and $V$?. $M$ and $N$ are metric spaces which means that $U$ and $V$ are open balls according to their respective metric, then I could write $$U=B_{U}(x,\delta)=\{y\in M:d(x,y)<\delta\}$$ $$V=B_{V}(x',\epsilon)=\{y'\in N:d'(x',y')<\epsilon\}$$

I would like to pick $r$ in order that $\pi_{1}^{-1}(B_1((x,y),r))\subset U$ and $\pi_{2}^{-1}(B_1((x',y'),r))\subset V$. I have thought two different ways of working this part, but I don't know which of them is right

$(1a)$ One of the ideas to solve this problem was to set $r<\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{min}\{\delta,\epsilon\}$. Doing this I believe that from $d(x,y)+d'(x',y')<r$ I can conclude that $d(x,y)<\delta$ and $d'(x',y')<\epsilon$, therefore the ball is included in the set.

$(2a)$ On second thoughts, maybe $(1a)$ was excessive and considering that the set $U\times V$ would have a diameter of $\delta+\epsilon$ according to the metric $d_1$, maybe it would be enough just to sed $r<\delta+\epsilon$ so the open ball would lie inside $U\times V$?

Now I will assume the open ball is given, how can I pic $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ to have $U\times V$ inside the ball?.Taking $\delta=\epsilon < \frac{1}{2}r$ seems to be enough.

Does this prove that $T=T_1$?

$(2)$ Now the ball $B_2$ would be given by $$B_2((x,y),r)=\{(x',y'):\operatorname{max}\{d(x,x'),d'(y,y')\}<r\}$$

Here I don't know how to proceed, my problem with this is that I need to find a relation between $r$ and $\delta,\epsilon$ in order to define the inclusions as I did before, but I believe I need to know more about $d(x,x')$ and $d'(y,y')$ if I were to define $r$.

Comment: TL:DR but I left a partial answer below :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> my guess here just consider the topology induced by the metric as well
>   as the product topology and show that they are included in each other.

Yes, exactly. As you noted, if $T$ is the product topology then an open set in $T$ is of the form $U \times V$ where $U$ is open in $(M,d)$ adn $V$ is open in $(N,d')$. To show $T=T_1$ you can show that

(i) for $(x,y) \in U \times V$ there exists $ \delta$ such that $B_{d_1}((x,y),\delta ) \subseteq U \times V$

and

(ii) If $B_{d_1}((x,y), r)$ is an open ball (in $T_1$) and $(x',y') \in B_{d_1}((x,y), r)$ then there exists $U \times V$ in the product topology such that $(x',y') \in U \times V \subseteq  B_{d_1}((x,y), r)$

The same two proofs with $d_1$ replaced by $d_2$ will yield $T = T_2$.

Now regarding $T = T_1$:

> $(1a)$ One of the ideas to solve this problem was to set
>   $r<\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{min}\{\delta,\epsilon\}$.
>   Doing this I believe that from $d(x,y)+d'(x',y')<r$ I can conclude
>   that $d(x,y)<\delta$ and $d'(x',y')<\epsilon$, therefore the ball is
>   included in the set.

Yes that's also correct. This appears to be direction (ii) above: 
Let $U \times V$ be open in $T$ and $(x,y) \in U \times V$ and consider $B((x,y),r)$ where $r < {\min (\delta , \varepsilon) \over 2}$. Then for any $(x',y') \in  B((x,y),r)$ we have 
$$ d_1 ((x,y), (x',y')) = d(x,x') + d(y,y') < r$$

In particular, $d(x,x') < \delta$ and $d(y,y') < \varepsilon$ hence $x' \in U$ and $y' \in V$ and hence $(x',y') \in U \times V$, showing that $B((x,y),r) \subseteq U \times V$ hence $U \times V$ is open in $T_1$.

> (2a)...

From the above you can see that $r = \delta + \varepsilon$ does not work.

> Now I will assume the open ball is given, how can I pick $\delta$ and
>   $\epsilon$ to have $U\times V$ inside the ball? Taking
>   $\delta=\epsilon < \frac{1}{2}r$ seems to be enough.
>
> Does this prove that $T=T_1$?

No but almost. Let $B_{d_1}((x,y),r)$ be an open ball in $T_1$ and $(x',y') \in B((x,y),r)$. You want to find an open set in $T$ that contains $(x',y')$ and is contained in $B((x,y),r)$. Let $R = {\min (r-d_1((x,y),(x',y'), d_1((x,y),(x',y'))\over 2}$ and consider the set $B_d(x', R) \times B_{d'}(y',R)$ (open in $T$). Then $d_1((x,y),(x',y')) = d(x,x') + d(y,y') < \min( r-d_1((x,y),(x',y'), d_1((x,y),(x',y'))) < r$.

> (2)...

(2) is easier than (1): Note that if $\max (\delta, \varepsilon) < r$ then both $\delta < r$ and $\varepsilon < r$.

I hope this helps and if not leave me a comment.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure about the last part where you show that $B_{d}(x',r/2)\times B_{d'}(y',r/2)\subset B_{d_1}((x,y),r)$, what if $(x',y')$ is really close to the boundary of $B_{d_1}((x,y),r)$?, this is, looks like there is no restriction to have taken $(x',y')$ such that $\frac{1}{2}<d_1((x,y),(x',y')<r$ and then in particular $B_d(x',\frac{1}{2}r)$ wouldn't be a subset of $U$. I was considering it in a way that $U\times V$ would be also centered in $B_{d_1}$, something like $B_{d}(x,\frac{1}{2})\times B_{d'}(y,\frac{1}{2}r)$.

Comment: @Dante You're absolutely right, I was a bit in a hurry when I wrote this. The $r/2$ is a typo, let me correct it (the claim is still true of course).

Answer (score 5):

To prove that $d$ induces the product topo on $A \times B$, you want to show that every open set in $A\times B$ is a union of open balls $B_d(x_0, r) = \{ x \in A\times B$ such that $d(x,x_0) \lt r\}$.  Well every open set in $A\times B$ is a union of some basis open sets $U_i \times V_i$, you said.  And each $U_i, V_i$ is a union of open balls in the respective two given topologies.  So we have $U_i = \bigcup_{j \in J} B_1(a_j, r_j), \ \ V_i = \bigcup_{k \in K} B_2(b_k, s_k)$.  But taking the cartesian product of *arbitrary* unions is a union of cartesian products, of, in this case, products of the form $B_1 (a_j, r_j) \times B_2 (b_k, s_k)$. So given a point in the latter, it suffices to show that we can fit a $d$-ball in there, and hence in the larger union.  Well, let $x_0 = (a,b)$ be the point.  Choose $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that $B_d(x_0, \epsilon) = \{ (x,y) : d((x,y), (a,b)) \lt \epsilon\}$ is contained in that product.  Let's look at the defining property of the ball more explicitly:
$$
d((x,y), (a,b)) \lt \epsilon \\
\iff \\
d_1(x,a) + d_2(y,b) \lt \epsilon
$$
We want the above to imply that $(x,y) \in B_1 \times B_2$ (above), so simply choose the minimum radius of the two balls $B_1, B_2$, i.e. $\min\{r_j, s_k\} = \epsilon$, then by non-negativity of metrics you have that $(x,y)$ lies in the product of the two balls.

Since every point $z$ of every open set in $A\times B$, has such a $d$-ball around it, contained completely within the open set, then the open set is clearly an arbitrary union of those balls, and thus the topology is induced by that metric.