# Continuity of vector space operations in a normed space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Here's problem 4 immediately following section 2.3 in Erwine Kryszeg's book, *Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications*:

Show that in a normed space $X$, vector addition and scalar multiplication are continuous operations with respect to the norm; that is, the mappings defined by $(x,y) \mapsto x+y$ and $(\alpha,x) \mapsto \alpha x$ are continuous.

Now the map $(x,y) \mapsto x+y$ is a map from $X \times X$ to $X$; so we can consider $X\times X$ under the norm defined as follows: 
$$|| (x,y) ||_{X\times X} \colon= ||x||_X + ||y||_X$$ 
for all $(x,y) \in X \times X$. With this norm, we can easily prove the vector addition map to be continuous.

But what about the norm on $K \times X$ for the continuity of the scalar multiplication map? Here $K$ (either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) denotes the field of scalars.

Comment: What's your math question? Be specific. Also in the title

Comment: Please read the question again.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud Hagen was referring to the fact that you didn't supply a sensible title.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud What justifies the use of the norm? $$|| (x,y) ||_{X\times X} \colon= ||x||_X + ||y||_X$$ This question seems to be considering arbitrary norms, so any proof of continuity should be general to any norm. Is this correct?

Comment: @Muno: Continuity is defined with topology, so when we are asked to prove continuity, it means the continuity under an explicitly or implicitly given topology, not general to any topology. Here, the continuity is assumed under the topology induced by product norm of $X\times X$, which has many equivalent forms (See, e.g., Folland, Real Analysis, P153). Saaqib chose that form just for ease of proof. cf., Rudin, Functional Analysis, P4, "... the vector space operations are continuous 'in this topology'".

Comment: ... and it happens that the topology induced by product metric is identical to product topology. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781734/proving-a-metric-induces-the-product-topology.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood are the vector operations of $X \times X$ defined componentwise?

Comment: @JohnMars here the vector space operations on $X \times X$ are immaterial; all that is really needed is the product topology on $X \times X$ as determined by the topology on $X$.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood we need at least a vector sum, so that $||(x_0,x_1)-(y_0,y_1)||$ makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same idea that works for $+$:
$$\|(\alpha,x)\|_{K\times X}=|\alpha|+\|x\|.$$
In any case, you can endow $K\times X$ with the product topology and no explicit norm is required.

EDIT:

$$\eqalign{\|\alpha x - \alpha_0 x_0\|_X
  & = \|\alpha x - \alpha_0 x + \alpha_0 x - \alpha_0 x_0\|_X\cr
  &\le\|\alpha x - \alpha_0 x\|_X + \|\alpha_0 x - \alpha_0 x_0\|_X\cr
  & = |\alpha - \alpha_0|\cdot\|x\|_X + |\alpha_0|\cdot\|x-x_0\|_X\cr
  &\le(1+\|x_0\|_X)\cdot|\alpha - \alpha_0|+ |\alpha_0|\cdot\|x-x_0\|_X\cr
  &\le(1+\|x_0\|_X+|\alpha_o|)\|(\alpha-\alpha_0,x-x_0)\|_{K\times X}\cr
  & = (1+\|x_0\|_X+|\alpha_o|)\|(\alpha,x)-(\alpha_0,x_0)\|_{K\times X}.}$$
(Why $\|x\|_X\le 1+\|x_0\|_X$?)

Comment: Martin, how to come up with a proof using this norm? I've mangaed to figure out something like this: $$||\alpha x - \alpha_0 x_0||_X = ||\alpha x - \alpha_0 x + \alpha_0 x - \alpha_0 x_0||_X \leq  ||\alpha x - \alpha_0 x||_X + ||\alpha_0 x - \alpha_0 x_0||_X = |\alpha - \alpha_0| \cdot ||x||_X + |\alpha_0| \cdot ||x-x_0||_X.$$ Then how to bring in the norm you've given?

Comment: Martin, I would like to solve this problem in the particular setting of a map from the normed space $K\times X$ to the normed space $X$, not using any such notions as the product topology.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud, the missing ingredient is $|\cdot|\le\|\cdot\|_{K\times X}$, $\|\cdot\|\le\|\cdot\|_{K\times X}$

Comment: could you plese complete the proof for me? That would be really so kind of you!

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud, see the edit and think in the question.

Comment: so nice of you! Yes, I got it now! Wonderful!!

Answer (score 2):

The fields $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ are equipped with a standard topology (derived from the standard metric and the standard absolute value).

Comment: This much I know, but I'm not able to decide as to which norm should be defined on the Cartesian product $K \times X$ so that the map $f \colon K \times X \to X$ defined by $f(\alpha,x) \colon= \alpha x$ for all $(\alpha, x) \in K \times X$ to be continuous?

Answer (score 0):

There are many forms of product norm. See, for example, P153 of Folland "Real Analysis". Instead of the additive form of product norm $\|(x,y)\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$, here I use max form $\|(x,y)\|=\max(\|x\|,\|y\|)$ to prove continuity of scale multiplication $(\alpha,x)\mapsto \alpha x$. Note that the max form is equivalent to additive form, so they induce the same metric topology. Specifically, $\|(\alpha,x)\|_{K\times X}=\max(|\alpha|,\|x\|)$. From the definition of max form of product norm, it is easy to see $|\alpha|,\|x\|\le\max(|\alpha|,\|x\|)=\|(\alpha,x)\|_{K\times X}$. Denote the induced metric in $K\times X$ as $d$.

Now fix $\alpha_0$ and $x_0$. If $x_0=0$, $(\alpha,x)\mapsto \alpha x$ is a constant function, which is trivially continuous. In the following, we assume $x_0\ne0$.

Let
$$\begin{equation*}
A=\begin{cases}
\alpha_0+1 &\text{if $\alpha_0\ge0$,}\\
-(\alpha_0-1) &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
$$
For any $\epsilon>0$, let $$\delta=\min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2\|x_0\|},A,\frac{\epsilon}{2A}).$$
Then as long as $d\bigl((\alpha,x),(\alpha_0,x_0)\bigr)<\delta$, we have $|\alpha x-\alpha_0x_0|<\epsilon$, establishing the continuity of scale multiplication. This is because, when it is the case,
$$\eqalign{d\bigl((\alpha,x),(\alpha_0,x_0)\bigr)
&=\|(\alpha,x)-(\alpha_0,x_0)\|_{K\times X}\cr
&=\|(\alpha-\alpha_0,x-x_0)\|_{K\times X}\cr
&=\max(|\alpha-\alpha_0|,\|x-x_0\|)\cr
&<\delta,}$$
so $|\alpha-\alpha_0|<1$ which forces $|\alpha|<A$. Likewise, we have $|\alpha-\alpha_0|<\frac{\epsilon}{2\|x_0\|}$ and $\|x-x_0\|<\frac{\epsilon}{2A}$. As a result,
$$\eqalign{\|\alpha x - \alpha_0 x_0\|
  & = \|\alpha x - \alpha x_0 + \alpha x_0 - \alpha_0 x_0\|\cr
  &\le\|\alpha x - \alpha x_0\| + \|\alpha x_0 - \alpha_0 x_0\|\cr
  & = |\alpha|\|x-x_0\| + |\alpha-\alpha_0|\|x_0\|\cr
  &<A\frac{\epsilon}{2A} + \frac{\epsilon}{2\|x_0\|}\|x_0\|\cr
  & = \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.}$$